# object key assigned parameters return undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a simulation and am working on the moving function. In the update function I have two things going on: a for loop that goes through each key in the object `wolves` and two functions `move(x, y, up, down, left, right)` and `draw(x, y, w, h, color`. I used `wolves["wolf" + [i]]` so when more wolves are added it will cycle through each one individually. When `move()` is invoked the parameters are assigned via the object key. The problem is the values return undefined (as shown in the snippet). Any help is very appreciated

```js
var wolves = {
  wolf0: {
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    w: 10,
    h: 10,
    up: false,
    down: false,
    left: false,
    right: false
  }
};
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
var movement = ["up", "down", "left", "right"];

//styles
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "black";
body[0].style.overflow = "hidden";
body[0].style.margin = "0px";

//update
var update = setInterval(function(){
  //clear anything left over from the last frame;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  //loop through wolves object and update each key
  for(i = 0; i < Object.keys(wolves).length; i++){
    var wolf = wolves["wolf" + i];
    move(wolf.x, wolf.y, wolf.up, wolf.down, wolf.left, wolf.right);
    //then draw to the canvas
    draw(wolf.x, wolf.y, wolf.w, wolf.h, "blue");
  }
}, 1000);

function draw(x, y, w, h, color){
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
  context.fill();
}

function move(x, y, up, down, left, right){
 var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 0;
 up = this.up;
 down = this.down;
 left = this.left;
 right = this.right;
 x = this.x;
 y = this.y;
 up = false;
 down = false;
 left = false;
 right = false;
 switch(movement[ran]){
  case "up":
   up = true;
   console.log("going up");
  break;
  case "down":
   down = true;
   console.log("going down");
  break;
  case "left":
   left = true;
   console.log("going left");
  break;
  case "right":
   right = true;
   console.log("going right");
  break;
  default:
   console.log("movement hasn't happend, the ran number is: " + ran);
  break;
 }
 if(up){
  y--;
  console.log("y--;");
 }
 if(down){
  y++;
  console.log("y++;");
 }
 if(left){
  x--;
  console.log("x--;");
 }
 if(right){
  x++;
  console.log("x++;");
 }
 console.log("x " + this.x);
 console.log("y " + this.y);
}
```

```html
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" height="768px" width="1366px"/>
</body>
```

Comment: `wolves["wolf" + [i]]` should not have the [] in it.

Comment: I put that there so later on when more and more wolves appear it will cycle through each one... or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It should be `"wolf" + i`

Comment: so it should look like `wolves."wolf" + i;`?

Comment: no it would still have the bracket notation.... ["wolf" + i]

Comment: apart from that you can send `wolf` object to move method, because `this.x` has no reference.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kukicvladimir/rgm0ehy8/) how to adjust move method so it has coordinates and all wolf properties.

Comment: I guess I was over thinking it a little, I'm new to inheritance but thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var wolves = {
  wolf0: {
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    w: 10,
    h: 10,
    up: false,
    down: false,
    left: false,
    right: false
  }
};
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
var movement = ["up", "down", "left", "right"];

//styles
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "black";
body[0].style.overflow = "hidden";
body[0].style.margin = "0px";

//update
var update = setInterval(function(){
  //clear anything left over from the last frame;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  //loop through wolves object and update each key
  for(i = 0; i < Object.keys(wolves).length; i++){
    var wolf = wolves["wolf" + [i]];
    move(wolf.x, wolf.y, wolf.up, wolf.down, wolf.left, wolf.right);
    //then draw to the canvas
    draw(wolf.x, wolf.y, wolf.w, wolf.h, "blue");
  }
}, 1000);

function draw(x, y, w, h, color){
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
  context.fill();
}

function move(x, y, up, down, left, right){
 var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 0;
 up = up;
 down = down;
 left = left;
 right = right;
 x = x;
 y = y;
 up = false;
 down = false;
 left = false;
 right = false;
 switch(movement[ran]){
  case "up":
   up = true;
   console.log("going up");
  break;
  case "down":
   down = true;
   console.log("going down");
  break;
  case "left":
   left = true;
   console.log("going left");
  break;
  case "right":
   right = true;
   console.log("going right");
  break;
  default:
   console.log("movement hasn't happend, the ran number is: " + ran);
  break;
 }
 if(up){
  y--;
  console.log("y--;");
 }
 if(down){
  y++;
  console.log("y++;");
 }
 if(left){
  x--;
  console.log("x--;");
 }
 if(right){
  x++;
  console.log("x++;");
 }
 console.log("x " + x);
 console.log("y " + y);
}
```

```html
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" height="768px" width="1366px"/>
</body>
```

I have changed for you. You shouldn't use `this` statement because of your function not a class. You just passing your object's attr. to your function params.

Comment: Thank you, both for solving the problem and telling me when to use `this` statements, those always mess me up!

Comment: No problem. Good luck on your project! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous problems in this code. See the below example of minimal changes to get it working (the movement is subtle since you are only moving it `1` unit at a time):

```js
var wolves = {
  wolf0: {
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    w: 10,
    h: 10,
    up: false,
    down: false,
    left: false,
    right: false
  }
};
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
var movement = ["up", "down", "left", "right"];

//styles
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "black";
body[0].style.overflow = "hidden";
body[0].style.margin = "0px";

//update
var update = setInterval(function(){
  //clear anything left over from the last frame;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  //loop through wolves object and update each key
  for(i = 0; i < Object.keys(wolves).length; i++){
    var wolf = wolves["wolf" + i];
    move(wolf);
    //then draw to the canvas
    draw(wolf.x, wolf.y, wolf.w, wolf.h, "blue");
  }
}, 1000);

function draw(x, y, w, h, color){
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
  context.fill();
}

function move(wolf){
 var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 0;

 switch(movement[ran]){
  case "up":
   wolf.y--
   console.log("going up");
    break;
  case "down":
   wolf.y++
   console.log("going down");
    break;
  case "left":
   wolf.x--
   console.log("going left");
    break;
  case "right":
   wolf.x++
   console.log("going right");
    break;
  default:
   console.log("movement hasn't happend, the ran number is: " + ran);
  break;
 }
}
```

```html
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" height="768px" width="1366px"/>
</body>
```

You are passing in arguments `x, y, up, down, left, right` only to immediately reassign them. This indicates something very wrong. You are also not updating `wolf` or maintaining any reference to the wolf's new position. If you instead pass `wolf` into `move` you can update the object, and then draw it in the interval.

Answer (score 0):

you can send `wolf + i` to `move(wolf)` and as it passes by reference you can get updated values stored in `wolf + i`, which helps you in drawing the simulation. Also you don't need to use `this` inside `move()`.

```js
var wolves = {
  wolf0: {
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    w: 10,
    h: 10,
    up: false,
    down: false,
    left: false,
    right: false
  }
};
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
var movement = ["up", "down", "left", "right"];

//styles
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "black";
body[0].style.overflow = "hidden";
body[0].style.margin = "0px";

//update
var update = setInterval(function(){
  //clear anything left over from the last frame;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  //loop through wolves object and update each key
  for(i = 0; i < Object.keys(wolves).length; i++){
    var wolf = wolves["wolf" + i];
    move(wolf)
    //then draw to the canvas
    draw(wolf.x, wolf.y, wolf.w, wolf.h, "blue");
  }
}, 1000);

function draw(x, y, w, h, color){
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
  context.fill();
}

function move(wolf){
 var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 0;
 up = wolf.up;
 down = wolf.down;
 left = wolf.left;
 right = wolf.right;
 x = wolf.x;
 y = wolf.y;
 up = false;
 down = false;
 left = false;
 right = false;
 switch(movement[ran]){
  case "up":
   up = true;
   console.log("going up");
  break;
  case "down":
   down = true;
   console.log("going down");
  break;
  case "left":
   left = true;
   console.log("going left");
  break;
  case "right":
   right = true;
   console.log("going right");
  break;
  default:
   console.log("movement hasn't happend, the ran number is: " + ran);
  break;
 }
 if(up){
  y--;
  console.log("y--;");
 }
 if(down){
  y++;
  console.log("y++;");
 }
 if(left){
  x--;
  console.log("x--;");
 }
 if(right){
  x++;
  console.log("x++;");
 }
 console.log("x " + x);
 console.log("y " + y);
    wolf.x = x;
    wolf.y = y;
}
```

```html
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" height="768px" width="1366px"/>
</body>
```